# How can I reliably run a jquery script after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm attempting to get some jquery code to run after a sharepoint page loads, the code being:

```
$(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();
```

I've been using the following to load the code after the page loads, but it does not seem to be very reliable (it will work sometimes and other times it wont):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
        $(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();
});
</script>
```

are there any other good methods for achieving this? I'm not sure what's going on, sharepoint could be at fault, but I figured I would try fiddling around with the script a bit more first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an auto-executing function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    $(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();
  } ());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is SharePoint 2010 or above, you can use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourfunction,"SP.JS")` to keep your code from firing until after the SP.JS library has loaded (or you can put any other library in the second parameter for a similar effect).

If this is in a web part and you don't want it to execute until other web parts on the page are fully loaded, make sure the web part containing the script is **below** the other web parts.

As a last resort, you could execute it on a delay using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, but that's ugly.

Comment: Hello, so could I just do:

$(window).load(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded($(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();,"SP.JS")
});

? thank you

Comment: Almost! The first parameter of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` needs to be a reference to a function, not an actual function call. So you could do `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded($(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click,"SP.JS");` or `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){$(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();},"SP.JS");`

Comment: thanks! still does not seem to be working though unfortunately, would it matter if this script is located within a script editor webpart? Here is how things are configured right now: http://imgur.com/cSu7YND. I'm trying to get things setup so that the script will fire on every page load and collapse any expanded list groups.

If i put something like alert("test"); in the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded function, it will trigger correctly, it's just the .click function that does not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default behaviour by using   e.preventDefault(); within the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click(function(e) {
        // We're going to stop the default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //some code here
    });
</script>
```